# Is there a DFA with $k+2$ states which its reverse has $2^k$ states

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language

I am trying to figure out if there exists a DFA $M$ with $k+2$ states (for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$ ) so that every automaton which accepts $L(M)^R$ has at least $2^k$ states.
I am trying to find an example of such a DFA, any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [reverse automata mininum states](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588205/reverse-automata-mininum-states)

Comment: This question says "I'm trying to find out if such a DFA exists" and that question is "Show that all such DFA have at least $2^k$ states." That's not the same question, although I can see why it looks like one.

Comment: @rschwieb You are correct the question is about existence of such DFA, I've found one using hhsaffar hint.

Comment: Cross-posted on CS.SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18648/755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*:

No DFA with fewer than $2^k$ states can recognize the language $C_k$ consisting of all strings of $a$ and $b$ that have an $a$ in the $k$th position from the end.